# Asus Strix GTX970 Unable to get 1920x1080 Resolution Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution

Been using linux off and on for a while now, and I have never had a graphics card issue until now. Built a new PC, was running Windows 8.1 on it. Ran just fine, I was able to pull 1920x1080 all day long with no issues. Install Ubuntu 14.04 to make the final push away from Windows and I have had these graphics card issue for the last 3 days.

System Specs:

i7 4790k 16GB DDR3 256GB Samsung EVO Pro Asus Stix GTX970 Asus Sabertooth (no embedded graphics)

AOC F22 Monitor 1920x1080 @ 60HZ

I installed various Nvidia drivers and I can not pull 1920x1080.
346 will only allow for 800x600 resolution
352 will only allow for 1024x740 (or something). I tried adding the 1920x1080 resolution using xrandr, and I received an error message and I was not able to do it.

I have read a ton of different Nvidia driver install guides (to many to list) and I have never been able to pull a 1920x1080 resolution.

I want to stick with linux, however this has really pissed me off. Any assistance would be awesome.

Xrandr Output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 800 x 600, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected primary 800x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        60.3*+
Unknown-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Ubuntu Drivers Output:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000013C2sv00001043sd00008508bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-346-updates - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-346 - distro non-free recommended
```

Comment: Any ideas? I am really stuck on this.

Comment: How is your monitor connected to the video card? Are you using an HDMI, DVI, or VGA?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to install the NVIDIA drivers from nvidia.com

1. Download the driver from http://www.geforce.com/drivers
2. Go to your downloads folder, right click on NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-355.11.run, and select *Properties*. Click on the *Permissions* tab and place a check mark in *Allow executing file as program*.
3. Open up Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
4. In Terminal type the following to edit the blacklist.conf file inorder to blacklist drivers that will interfere with installing the NVIDIA Drivers:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```
5. At the end of the blacklist.conf file add the following lines:

   ```
   blacklist nouveau
   blacklist nvidiafb
   blacklist rivafb
   blacklist rivatv
   blacklist vga16fb
   ```
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save the file. Followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to confirm.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit Nano and return back to the Terminal.
8. Next, we need to remove any NVIDIA drivers already on the system by typing the following command in Terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
   ```
9. Restart Ubuntu and return to the login screen.
10. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a virtual console.
11. Enter your user name and password to log in. Note that when typing in a password, you will not get an indicator on the screen like asterisks.
12. Stop the display manager running in Ubuntu by typing the following command:

    ```
    sudo service lightdm stop
    ```
13. Type the following command to install the NVIDIA Drivers:

    ```
    sudo ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-355.11.run
    ```
14. From here, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the license. And then did the same to select 'Yes' and 'OK' all the way to the end. I also let the installation run the nvidia-xconfig to update my X configuration file.
15. Once everything is installed, reboot Ubuntu by typing the following command:

    ```
    sudo shutdown -r now
    ```
16. Your PC will reboot with the new drivers installed, and hopefully you get the full 1080p resolution.