# Ubuntu 14.04 No Desktop

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

Before I start, this is on my inspiron 7707 windows 8.1/Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot which has Intel HD 4000 and Nvidia GeForce GT 750m.

I have been trying to update my Nvidia drivers, which by itself is proving to be horrifically difficult so following some instructions here or on another ubuntu forum (cant remember and dont have access to the history) I purged nvidia and bumblebee as well as prime, I believe, though I'm not sure.

After downloading the 352.55 drivers I eventually just switched to tty1 and ran the command

```
    sudo service gdm stop
```

then executed the nvidia driver .run file, where I encountered an error along the lines of "Could not load kernel module", so I hit enter and then

```
    sudo service gdm start
```

and then, well, nothing. tty7 was just a black screen with the underscore cursor at the top left, and it seemed to repeatedly try to reload which prevented me from using another tty until I stopped gdm again. Can anyone give me an idea about what to do? I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling ubuntu-gnome-destop and apt-get update, which also did nothing, I also started lightdm which let me login on tty7 but for some reason it was a ubuntu dekstop not gnome, and it too kept restarting. However, after a reboot it wouldnt work either, instead I was confronted with a pop up warning about low graphics settings, but still just a black screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[edit] While looking around on one of the virtual terminals I noticed a new file in my home folder named "core"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to restart the computer and the service should auto restart:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

To properly install proprietary NVIDIA drivers, you can check the following post where I have posted a step-by-step guide:

[Asus Strix GTX970 Unable to get 1920x1080 Resolution Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/684181/asus-strix-gtx970-unable-to-get-1920x1080-resolution-ubuntu-14-04)

Hope this helps out!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however that doesn't work for me. I've had to do a fresh install (about 5 times) every time i try to install drivers. The only time i can get it to somewhat work is after a fresh install, i go to Additional Drivers and select the Nvidia-346 Binary drivers, however I need the 352 in order to use CUDA 7.5 and when I install a driver using the .run file I always end up with a login loop after rebooting; When I look  /var/crash the error is labeled as a keyboard error, oddly enough

Comment: Since you are running both an NVIDIA and Intel graphics card, you can install the Bumblebee drivers as noted at the following link:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04